# unity 5 preferbs ui not showing when click on object

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

i have a a problem to active UI from prefabs when click on object using OnMouseDown code

```
public class TreeManager : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject FuncUI;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () { 



}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (FuncUI.activeInHierarchy == false)
{
        FuncUI.SetActive (true);
    }
else
    {
    FuncUI.SetActive (false);
    }
 }  

public void ExitOn()
{
    Application.Quit ();
}
 }
```

this OnMouseDown code is working if both object and gameobject UI is on hierarchy. but it not work if both i use from prefabs.. what i need to change so i can make it work for prefabs? my function UI is from canvas. when i click on the object, the FuncUI will appear on screen. this code i put inside the object that i want to click to appear FuncUI

Comment: With `prefab` you mean stuff that is in the assets folder, not actually in the scene? If so, you can't make that work because stuff that is in the assets folder practically is not in the game.

Comment: ouh.  how actually i can make it work? i mean.. i cant drag item in scene into prefabs gameobject.. it must be either both in scene or booth in prefabs.. if booth in scene. the code is working, but if booth in assets, it wont working.. or i use wrong code? i actually want the object in prefabs spawn in scene, so i can click the object that spawn in scene to show a UI

Comment: Well, as said: If something is not in the scene, you can't interact with it. It **has** to be in the scene (or connected to something in the scene if it is a script) so you can interact with it in whichever way.

Comment: A `prefab` is just a blueprint for easier duplication.

Comment: ouh ok... tq.. now i understand.. i need to find other way .. how about using this code
 "void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
 {

  foreach (Transform child in CoinPanel.transform)
  {
   if (child.gameObject.tag == collision.gameObject.tag) 
   {
    string c = child.Find ("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text;
    Ccount = System.Int32.Parse(c) + 1;
    child.Find ("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + Ccount;
    return;
   }
  }"
how i can change form collision to click? i am thinking about use this.. but i not sure how to change from collision to click function

Comment: if i use this.. i can assign this script into player that always in the scene

Comment: I don't quite get what you want. Why don't you put your UI into the scene in some way? Either directly in the editor or with `Instantiate` on runtime.

Comment: the UI actually i have  it on my scene, but i cant drag scene UI into prefabs object that i placed the script... the game i trying to do is farm game.. all tree have this same UI.. the tree only appear if i click on the places i want it to spawn....  my problem right now.. when the tree is complete grow, i should able to click the tree to display the UI.. but right now the UI not appear if the tree is from prefabs even it have script on it to be able to click.. the scene UI cannot be insert into the prefabs GameObject column.

Comment: Everything that you want to use has to be in the scene, either directly from the start or instantiated on runtime. It sounds like you have a tree prefab that you place with instantiate into the scene. These instantiated trees should, if setup correctly, receive click events.